# No aparece la opción "Language" en Android Studio al intentar crear un Empty Activity

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy aprendiendo a realizar Aplicaciones Móviles en “Android Studio + Java” no puede ser de otra manera, tengo que aprenderlo así.
La cuestión es que vi un tutorial, y al elegir el template “Empty Activity” abre una ventanita de configuración. La ventana que abre en el tutorial es esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cuestión es que al recordar que necesitaba configurar el nuevo proyecto “empty activity” en “Language Java”… borre el proyecto, y quise crearlo de nuevo, pero para mi sorpresa, no aparece el ítem “Language”. Aquí les muestro una foto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, al usar otros templates, sí me aparece el ítem para elegir “language”; aquí les muestro una foto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo tengo que hacer para que me vuelva a aparecer la opción *Language*? Esto probé y no funcionó:

- Desinstalé “Android Studio” y usé la opción de “borrar configuraciones de usuario”.
- Borré los archivos de “%APPDATA%\Google\AndroidStudio”.
- Volví a instalar Android Studio y sigue igual.

Comment: Esto se debe a Google está dirigiéndonos de alguna forma a usar el lenguage Kotlin como lenguaje oficial para la plataforma Android. Agregué respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En las últimas versiones el IDE cambió y ahora (en la versión 2022.3.1) la selección de plantillas se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La plantilla que quieres utilizar ahora crea una actividad vacía que utiliza [Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose), una forma nueva y más rápida de crear aplicaciones con programación declarativa.

Si quieres programar de forma tradicional, por vistas, crea un nuevo proyecto con alguna plantilla que no diga Compose, ni TV, ni nada de relojes inteligentes a menos que eso quieras.

En la imagen puedes ver que ahora la plantilla vacía tradicional se llama **Empty Views Activity**.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me sirvió mucho :D

Answer (score 1):

El no poder cambiar el lenguaje de programación, no es un error, simplemente se debe a que **Google está tratando tácitamente de dirigirnos a usar únicamente el lenguaje <kbd>Kotlin</kbd> como desarrollo para la plataforma android, incluso actualmente hay mecanismos, clases, métodos que son obsoletos en Java y la única opción para poder actualizarlos es usando el lenguaje <kbd>Kotlin</kbd>.**

Te sugiero revisar:

[Enfoque de prioridad de **Kotlin** en Android](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/first?hl=es-419)

> **En Google I/O 2019, anunciamos que el desarrollo de Android estaría cada vez más orientado a <kbd>Kotlin</kbd>.** Seguimos manteniendo ese
> compromiso. Kotlin es un lenguaje de programación expresivo y conciso
> que permite reducir los errores de código comunes y se integra
> fácilmente en las apps existentes. Si quieres crear una app para
> Android, te recomendamos que comiences con <kbd>Kotlin</kbd> a fin de aprovechar
> sus mejores funciones.

---

Si deseas usar el lenguaje <kbd>Java</kbd> en tu proyecto android, al seleccionar tu proyecto **es necesario selecciones "Empty Views Activity"**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después ya podrás seleccionar el lenguaje, **<kbd>Kotlin</kbd>** o **<kbd>Java</kbd>**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me sirvió bastante :D